# Dispersive media, imaginary velocity

Tags: complex-numbers, dispersion, phase-velocity

In a dispersive medium we ave usually 2 dispersion laws:

1. One that relates frequencies and Real Wavenumbers;
2. One that relates frequencies and Imaginary Wavenumbers;

With 1. I can find group and phase velocity.
In some other applications different from mine, which is fluid mechanics, they find a loss factor with 2. What I have understood is that the 2. can give us information about the attenuation, and then (I assume) about a possible contrast to phase and group velocity. Is there a way I can calculate the effect on the phase or group velocity due to the attenuation related to 2.?

P.S. For the ones who may think I did not do a specific reference research

1. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) (which was the starting research) states that for the group velocity formula "the imaginary part of the wavevector is arbitrarily discarded", and no additional information is provided.
2. I have searched in the books suggested by wikipedia, such as the one of Brillouin but I didn't find anything related to my question.
3. I have found some informative material, but their explanations are always too related to subject which I am not an expert, such as electromagnetism or optic or physics of plasma. I have tried to read it, but I was very difficult to me